# Problems with data re-organization

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm chunking up a `DataFrame`, then want to stick an `ID` column (filled with the pos value) on the chunk and build a new `DataFrame` out of the stacked chunks.  I'm trying this...

```
def organizer(org_seq, size, overlap):
    new_seq = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(org_seq.columns.values))
    for pos in range(0, len(org_seq) - size, size-overlap):
        seq_holder = org_seq.iloc[pos:pos + size]
        seq_holder.insert(0, 'ID', pos)
        new_seq.append(seq_holder, ignore_index=True)
    return new_seq
```

**EDIT** this modification produced the correct behavior however it was taxing

```
        new_seq = new_seq.append(seq_holder, ignore_index=True)
```

**END EDIT**

I'm getting an empty DataFrame back from this function.  What I'd like is exampled here:

DataFrame in:

```
0 a b
1 a b
2 a b
3 a b
4 a b
5 a b
```

New `DataFrame` out:

```
0 a b pos-id
1 a b pos-id
2 a b pos-id
3 a b pos-id
1 a b pos-id
2 a b pos-id
3 a b pos-id
4 a b pos-id
2 a b pos-id
3 a b pos-id
4 a b pos-id
5 a b pos-id
```

I'll bet there's some simple data acrobatics built under the `DataFrame` hood that I'm missing. Any elegant solution would certainly be appreciated.

Comment: `new_seq.append` method returns a new object but does not modify `new_seq` itself.

Comment: is this one column? or 2 columns 'a' and 'b' with 'pos-id' as 3rd column?

Comment: column 'a' : column 'b' - added column 'pos-id'

Comment: Edited above.  Ankur's feedback produced the desired behavior; however, it is quite taxing on the processor.  I'll leave this open for a day or so if there is a more elegant solution that is more efficient. - Thanks